# Why is $p(x)=\int p(x,z) dz$ intractable for continuous $z$ in VAE?

Tags: variational-autoencoder, importance-sampling

In VAE we use the importance sampling trick to use $q_\phi(z|x)$ to help maximize $\log p_\theta(x)=\log \int p_\theta(x,z)dz\ge \int q_\phi(z|x)\log \frac{p_\theta(x,z)}{q_\phi(z|x)} dz$. Meanwhile, when we're dealing with something like $\int q_\phi(z|x) f(\cdot) dz$, we can change the integral into an expectation $E_{z\sim q_\phi(z|x) }f(\cdot)$ and evaluate it by sampling some (or one) $z$ in the training process.

So the problem is, why can't we do the same thing with $p_\theta(x)$ by writing it as $\int p_\theta(x,z)dz=\int p(z)p_\theta(x|z) dz=E_{z\sim p(z)}p_\theta(x|z)$ and sample some $z$ from the std normal distribution?

Or from another perspective, optimal $q_\phi(z|x)$ should be $p_\theta(z|x)$. Then $p_\theta(x)= \int q_\phi(z|x)\frac{p_\theta(x,z)}{q_\phi(z|x)} dz=\int p_\theta(z|x)\frac{p_\theta(x,z)}{p_\theta(z|x)} dz=\int p_\theta(z|x)p_\theta(x) dz$. Then why do we have to split $ p_\theta(x,z)$ into $p_\theta(z|x)p_\theta(x)$ instead of $p(z)p_\theta(x|z)$?

I know sampling using $E_{z\sim p(z)}p_\theta(x|z)$ makes no sense because $z$ doesn't help with the training at all and $p_\theta(x|z)$ will have to fit all $x$ for all $z$. But this seems mathematically equivalent, so I have no idea why sampling $z$ is not possible, while sampling $q_\phi(z|x)$ is the standard for evaluating the integral.